# Java - regex any string between < and >

Tags: java, regex, string

I use a `String` where I need to get rid of any occurence of: `<` any string here `>`

I tried `line = line.replaceAll("<[.]+>", "");`

but it gives the same `String`... How can I delete the `<` any string between `>` substrings?

Comment: Remove the `[]`: `<.+>` - this is greedy though and may give you unexpected results. You should use `<.*?>` or `<[^>]*>`, but the latter is more correct.

Comment: can you show us some input output examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my original comment...

### Brief

Your regex `<[.]+>` says to match `<`, followed by the dot character `.` (literally) one or more times, followed by `>`

Removing `[]` will get you a [semi-appropriate answer](https://regex101.com/r/epUqbT/1). The problem with this is that it's greedy, so it'll actually replace everything from the first occurrence of `<` to the last occurrence of `>` in the entire string (see the link to see it in action).

What you want is to either make the quantifier lazy or use a character class to ensure it's not going past the ending character.

---

### Code

#### Method 1 - Lazy Quantifier

This method `.*?` matches any character any number of times, but as few as possible

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/epUqbT/2)

```
<.*?>
```

#### Method 2 - Character Set

This method `[^>]*` matches any character except `>` any number of times

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/epUqbT/3)

```
<[^>]*>
```

**Note**: This method performs much better than the first.

Answer (score 2):

```
line = line.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```